# What's the union of a set whose members are sets? like here?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The definition of union of a set in my book is the set formed by all the members of the members of the set.

But if Z is a set formed by several sets and 
Z = {{{1,2},3,5}, {3,4}, {6},6, 7}
what's the union of Z?
Is it, maybe {{1,2},3,5,4,6,7} ? or what is it then?

Then if we call W= {{1,2},3,5,4,6,7}
Then if I'm right the union of W might be X= {1,2,3,5,4,6,7} ?
Then the union pulverized W in such a way that X isn't a subset of W and X isn't a subset of Z either because for example the element
1 that is in X isn't a member of Z  ? or is it in some way secretly or whatever? because my intuition said that the parts of the whole HAD TO BE a subset of the union of the whole but if I have learned something is that I can't never be sure by intuitions how things turn out to be in the end in maths

(Forgive me for using the word pulverized but I don't know how to call that)

These symbols {} in sets ruined my life, my head was full of doubts about basic set theory, and the answers I found are too abstract for me to understand and everybody except me seemed to know everything and assume everything as obvious so obvious that nobody ever thought that I'd be asking myself these things and the teachers went on and I was incredibly full of much more doubts like these ones everywhere. And I don't say anything else because it was too depressing

Answer (score 4):

By definition $x\in\bigcup Z$ if and only if there is a $y\in Z$ such that $x\in y$. The possible choices for $y$ are $\big\{\{1,2\},3,5\big\},\{3,4\},\{6\},6$, and $7$. The members of $\big\{\{1,2\},3,5\big\}$ are $\{1,2\},3$, and $5$; those of $\{3,4\}$ are $3$ and $4$; and the only member of $\{6\}$ is $6$. So far, then, we know that $\{1,2\},3,4,5$ and $6$ are members of $\bigcup Z$. Assuming that you’re treating the non-negative integers as atomic entities that do not have members, that’s it:

$$\bigcup Z=\big\{\{1,2\},3,4,5,6\big\}\;.$$

$7$ is not a member of $\bigcup Z$, because there is no $y\in Z$ such that $7\in y$. The situation may look a little different, but $1$ and $2$ are also not members of $\bigcup Z$ for the same reason: there is no $y\in Z$ such that $1\in y$ or $2\in y$. (Note that $1$ and $2$ are **not** elements of $\big\{\{1,2\},3,5\big\}$.)

In the most common formalization of set theory, the answer would be different, because in that formalization $6=\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $7=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, so that

$$\bigcup Z=\big\{\{1,2\},0,1,2,3,4,5,6\big\}\;.$$

Comment: No problem. Been there!

Comment: @Lee: Got it; thanks.