# Understanding a double union of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have an exercise example from Goldrei's *Classical Set Theory (For Guided Independent Study)* and I am having trouble understanding the axiom of union examples.

Exercise: Given a set *F* of ordered pairs <a,b>, give a set in ZF in which all the a's and b's lie.

Solution:
A typical element <a,b> of *F* is a set {{a}, {a,b}}. Thus  $\cup $*F*   is the set of all {a}'s and {a,b}'s  for  <a,b> $\in$ *F*, so that $\cup $($\cup $*F*) is the set of all a's and b's for which <a,b> $\in$ *F*. As *F* is a set, $\cup $($\cup $*F*) is also a set, by the union axiom.

Question:
I am quite confused about the set of $\cup $($\cup $*F*) and what the elements are. So if I take {{a}, {a,b}} and use the axiom of union I get $\cup $*F* which results to the set {a,b}. But if I do another union i.e,
$\cup $($\cup $*F*) wouldn't my result just be {a,b} again? I understand elementary union (that we were taught in High school)  but since I am learning intro into set theory I'm having trouble grasping the axiom of union and understanding the union of the union of a set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example may help. Let
$$
F = \{(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1)\} = \{\{\{1\}, \{1, 2\}\}, \{\{2\}, \{2, 3\}\}, \{\{3\}, \{3, 1\}\}\}
$$
Then:
$$
\begin{align*}
\bigcup F &=\{\{1\}, \{1, 2\}, \{2\}, \{2, 3\}, \{3\}, \{3, 1\}\} 
\end{align*}
$$
And

$$
\begin{align*}
\bigcup\bigcup F &= \bigcup\{\{1\}, \{1, 2\}, \{2\}, \{2, 3\}, \{3\}, \{3, 1\}\} \\
 &= \{1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1\} \\
 &= \{1, 2, 3\}
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: This example helped me a lot thank you!!

Comment: What if the set F was like this: {{{1}, {1,2}}, {{2}, {2,3}}, 6}. Is 6 not part of union F?

Comment: In "pure" set theory, everything is a set and $6$ has a definition as a set (the usual definition due to von Neumann makes $6 = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$). Here both your example and the original example where ordered pairs are represented as sets show a difference between the set theory you are learning and traditional mathematical practice, where statements like $x \in (1, 2)$ or $y \in 6$ are not considered to be meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

> if I take $\{ \{ a \}, \{ a,b \} \}$ and use the axiom of union I get $\cup F$ which results to the set $\{ a,b \}$.

No; if $(a,b)=\{ \{ a \}, \{ a,b \} \} \in F$ we have that:

> $\{ a \}, \{ a,b \} \in \cup F$.

The first [union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_union) is needed in order to retrieve from the set $F$ of *pairs* the elements.

Then, we need a second "extraction" in order to retrieve $a,b$, from which $a, b \in \cup (\cup F)$.

Thus:

> > $\cup (\cup F) = \{ z \mid \exists w,a,b \ (w= \{ \{ a \}, \{ a,b \}\} \land w \in F \}$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I see what I did wrong now in the first union. The {} notation confuses me sometimes. It makes more sense now

Answer (score 0):

We have $$ x\in\bigcup  Y\iff \exists y\colon x\in y\in Y$$
and
$$ x\in\bigcup \bigcup  F\iff \exists y\colon x\in y\in \bigcup F\iff \exists y,z\colon x\in y\in z\in F$$
Hence if each element of $F$ is a Kuratowski pair, then we obtain the elements of elements elements of these pairs, so indeed what we want.

Comment: this particular part of the axiom of union formula confuses me: ∈⋃⟺∃:∈∈ , so x is an element of Union(Y) iff there exists a y and x is an element of y and y is an element of (Y). Does this just explain that x has to be an element of the set y and that set y is an element of set (Y)? Meaning that the union has to be a union of SETS not just elements? The reason I am confused is because I came across a stackexchange question where 7 is not part of the union and I still don't understand why it is not.

Comment: this is the link to the question i was referring to on stack, link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1853713/whats-the-union-of-a-set-whose-members-are-sets-like-here?rq=1